# Question mark, plus, minus preceding Prolog variable names

Tags: prolog

I've searched for an explanation to this but haven't found one. What do the question mark, plus sign, and minus sign that sometimes precede variable names in the description of a Prolog predicate mean?

Example:

```
predicate(?Variable1,+Variable2,-Variable3)
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

- `?` means: This variable can be either instantiated or not. Both ways are possible.
- `+` means: This variable is an *input* to the predicate. As such it must be instantiated.
- `-` means: This variable is an *output* to the predicate. It is usually non-instantiated, but may be if you want to check for a specific "return value".

Source: Chapter 4 of the SWI Prolog documentation.

Answer (score 4):

`+` means that `Variable2` is expected to be bound (to a term, or perhaps just some variable) -- you can think of this as *input* to `predicate/3`, which the predicate won't attempt to modify in execution.

`-` means that `Variable3` is expected to be bound by `predicate/3` in it's execution -- you can think of this as *output* from `predicate/3`. This doesn't mean it *can't* be bound, however, particularly if you know what to expect and are checking for success, but `predicate/3` is described as potentially binding (unifying) `Variable3` to something.

`?` means that `Variable1` can be *either* be bound (`+`, input) or not (`-`, output) - `predicate/3` should deal with both cases, if it accepts either.